# jQuery attribute selector, check attr exists but does not contain string

Tags: jquery

I have found a few similar questions relating to selecting attr which do not contain a string, but in my jQuery i want to check if the element has a lang attr but not the following string.

Here is my code:

```
    function lang(l) {
        $('div[lang]').hide().filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr('lang') === l;
        }).show();
    };

    if (document.cookie.match("language=en")) {
        lang("en");
    }
    else if (document.cookie.match("language=fr")) {
        lang("fr");
    }

    $(".en").click(function () {
        lang("en");
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (31536000000));
        document.cookie = "language=en; expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    })
    $(".fr").click(function () {
        lang("fr");
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (31536000000));
        document.cookie = "language=fr; expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    })
```

I basically want to show all elements with a certain language, and hide all others (the problem I currently have is that if the lang attr doesn't exist then it just hides everything...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```js
function lang(l) {
  $('div[lang]').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('lang') === l;
  }).show();
};

lang('en-gb');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div lang="en-gb">gb</div>
<div lang="en-us">us</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect... for some reason it is not hiding the incorrect elements on page load though... updated code is in my question.

Comment: sorry my bad, just needed to add document ready around the if statement. all working perfect now thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not()` with attribute contains selector. before that, you need to modify div selector to consider element with attribute with lang:

```
$('.div[lang]').not('[lang*="'+ l +'"]').hide();
```

Also you can optimize your code to:

```
function lang(l) {
  var $langDivs =  $('div[lang]')
  $langDivs.not('[lang*="'+ l +'"]').hide();
  $langDivs.filter('[lang*="'+ l +'"]').show();
}
```